# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage reporting "Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)"

Tags: ios

Can anyone explain (or point out the relevant FM covering) this function?

iPad 2, iOS 5.0.0, Xcode 4.2, project with ARC.

My project takes input from the camera and mixes it with various images, finally rendering it all on the screen.

As long as I don't get a memory warning, it works fine indefinitely with no memory leaks.

After a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, the first 5 times this function is called it fails saying "Failed to create `IOSurface` image (texture)". After that, the screen goes black and the program stops responding. I can press the home key and then kill the app.

My call looks like this:

```
    err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                   _videoTextureCache,
                                                   pixelBuffer,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   _textureWidth,
                                                   _textureHeight,
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                   0,
                                                   &_lumaTexture);
```

`_videoTextureCache` is originally created with this:

```
    //-- Create CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef for optimal CVImageBufferRef to GLES texture conversion.
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, (__bridge void *)_context, NULL, &_videoTextureCache);
    if (err) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate %d", err);
        return;
    }
```

`_videoTextureCache` is defined like this:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef _videoTextureCache;
```

Do I need to call something to release allocated memory when I get a memory warning?
Can I `nil` `_videoTextureCache` (so ARC can clean up memory), and then recreate it?

The only documentation I've found so far is comments in the `.h` where the function is declared, and that doesn't really seem to help.

Anyone know of other documentation?

-Ken

Comment: Is this related? https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/220

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling `CFRelease()` on your `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef` and `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` when you don't need them anymore?

Apple Source Code:

- [GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [RosyWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110)

Answer (score 1):

Not wanting to revive an old question, but I've just spent days trying to figure out the same problem (albeit on ios 8.4), and keep coming across this question when googling.

I've finally figured out that [for me at least] the `internalFormat` NEEDS to be `GL_RGBA`. I was foolishy using `GL_BGRA` because that's the internal format used on IOS, AND I was decoding my video as BGRA AND the docs say "this is how to decode GL_BGRA" but then I realised they use GL_RGBA in the docs/header comments.

The pixel format was happy as GL_RGBA or GL_BGRA (just colours flipped appropriately)

Comment: Thank you for the help, your observation is very useful